# Order of shuffled cards and decks

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

For a deck of six cards, I want to verify that an **inshuffle** has order $3$ and **outshuffle** has order $4$.

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Write each of these shuffles as a product of distinct cycles, at which point the question should be trivial.

Comment: @JohnColeman any chance you can point me in the right direction for reading material?

Comment: Or: just compose each shuffle with itself 3 or 4 times. If it is an abstract algebra question regarding permutations, you have probably discussed how to write permutations and how to compose (multiply) them.

Comment: Reading material about what?  How to represent a shuffle as a permutation?  I don't think there would be anything about that *specific* scenario, it is just one among many applications of permutations that should come naturally once one is familiar with the topic.  Without loss of generality, let the cards be labeled $1,2,3,4,5,6$ and let them begin in the deck in that same order.  Now... take a look at the resulting order of the cards after an inshuffle has occurred.  Write that order in the bottom line of $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\&\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: That would be a two-line representation of the permutation going on, which you can then convert to other representations of the permutation as you so desire, the most useful of which in this scenario might be in disjoint cyclic form as that form would scream out what the order of the permutation would be.  The order of a permutation is the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles appearing in a disjoint cyclic representation of that permutation.  Do so similarly for the outshuffle instead.

Comment: So do you mean, $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 1 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: No, that is an out-shuffle.  Both in and out shuffles are accomplished by taking the top half of the cards to create a different pile and then perfectly interleaving the piles together.  The difference between an inshuffle and an outshuffle is which of the piles gets the top card.  An inshuffle has the former top card as the second card in the result of the shuffle.  An outshuffle has the former top card remain as the new top card in the result.

Comment: Ok, so correction: $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 4 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 6 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, and we can represent that as products of disjoint cycles by following the train of thought $\begin{pmatrix}\color{red}{1}&\color{blue}{2}&3&\color{green}{4}&5&6\\\color{red}{4}&\color{blue}{1}&5&\color{green}{2}&6&3\end{pmatrix}$ that $\color{red}{1\mapsto 4}$ and then $\color{green}{4\mapsto 2}$ followed by $\color{blue}{2\mapsto 1}$ so one of the cycles is $(1~4~2)$, Similarly we find another cycle to be $(3~5~6)$, so the disjoint cyclic representation of the inshuffle permutation of a deck of six cards to be $(1~4~2)(3~5~6)$

Answer (score 1):

If original deck $(123456),$ shuffled deck is: $(142356)$ for out shuffle and $(415263)$ for in shuffle. For outshuffle, it is easy to see that 1 & 6 are fixed and the other 4 are involved in a cycle. So, there is one 4 length cycle or the order is 4. For in shuffle, you have 2 3 length cycles. LCM of the cycle lengths (which is order) is 3.